# Add Node.js backend to React project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git

So I have created a React app with

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

and written a few functions and some content to my web app. Now I do need to implement backend for connecting to my SQL database and reading/writing from there. It is my understanding that server-side logic (NodeJS) and front-end code (React) should be in same repository, but how exactly is that done? I should probably create `/backend` folder and `server.js` inside it, but where? In the same folder with `node_modules`, `public` and `src` or elsewhere? Also, it would be nice to know more about how information exchange between Node and React works so I can display data fetched from database with React. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to add a second `package.json` or `node_modules`. why not add a script to the current `package.json` which runs node? `"server": "node server.js"`?

Comment: As for sharing data between node and react, node can render react pages (easy to share data), but react would likely have to send node data via fetch/ajax.

Comment: it doenst really matter , in the end it depends on your endpoints. 
It can also be a totally different folder or server... 
Example: you can have your frontend App running on localhost:3000 and your Backend on localhost: 3001. 
Next you can define a proxy in your React App to route all API requests to the backend server.

Comment: @evolutionxbox So basically I just create server.js and include it in package.json? I don't need dependencies specifically for server-side?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer you probably will need dependencies for the server, but they can be added to the same project. Or you can have them as two completely separate projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development I have two folders on same level - `src` with react and `server` with node.
You start (e.g.)

- nodejs server on port 5000
- webpack-dev-server on port 3000

React communicates with backend via REST API. You have to proxy api requests to your server (part of webpack dev configuration):

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'static', 'public'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
      },
    },
  },
```

In production environment the react is compiled to `server/reactapp` subfolder and served with expressjs as any other webpage.

Part of webpack production:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'reactapp'),
    // publicPath: path.join('dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
```

In Express (or any other web framework) you then serve the /api path with your backend tasks.

This all means I have two separated development environments - server and react, which partly join till in production environment. They both have separated package.json and node_modules.
In newer versions I have replaced REST API communication with websocket, what needs some other settings in communication.

[image]

Comment: Is that a package.json file where that configuration code is located?

Comment: No, webpack.js - I have one for development and one for production.

Comment: node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ? That doesn't look like a configuration file on my Windows machine...

Comment: I have added my folder structure to my answer with description.

Comment: Thanks, I assume that contents of /server are automatically generated (modules and such). How do you do that?

Comment: Server is pure nodejs with Expressjs as web framework. It serves REST API requests from React. One of the paths is also the generated React application. It is generated by webpack.